# C++ allocates more bytes than asked?

Tags: c++

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        char *c = new char;

    cin.get();
}
```

In the above code, why does my program use 471MB memory instead of 10MB as one would expect?

Comment: How do you know 471MB consumed.

Comment: !@Ashiquzzaman: The task manager says so.

Comment: The task manager measures many things - which particular number are you looking at? Also note that the minimum allocation size is probably more than one byte - I'd expect at least 8, probably more.

Comment: @Alan Stokes: "Memory (Private Working Set)" in Windows

Comment: Is there a question here?  Yes, there is always overhead to allocations or anything else you do.

Comment: Subtract the allocated size before and after allocation (not the total memory size), and divide by 10000000. That gives you the overhead per allocation of one character.

Comment: @SuperHeroY: Task Manager is not a good indication. Memory allocation is not simple enough to bring it down to a single number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allocation of RAM comes from a combined effort of the runtime library and the operating system. In order to identify the one byte your example code requests, there is some structure which identifies this memory to the runtime. It is sometimes a double linked list, but it's defined by the operating system and runtime implementation.

You can analogize it this way: If you have a linked list container, what you're interested in is simply what you've placed inside each link, but the container must have pointers to the other links in the containers in order to maintain the linked list.

If you use a debugger, or some other debugging tool to track memory, these structures can be even larger, making each allocation more costly.

RAM isn't typically allocated out of an array, but it is possible to overload the new operator to change allocation behavior. It could be possible specifically allocate from an array (a large one in your example) so that allocations behaved as you seem to have expected, and in some applications this is a specific strategy to control memory and improve performance (though the details are usually more complex than that simple illustration).

Comment: Do you have any site/wikipdia page where I can read details on how I can avoid wasting memory by creating my own memory allocator?

Comment: What about `char* c= new char[10000000];` ?

Comment: @SuperHeroY The problem usually isn't with the default allocator but with the (bad) habits of the developer.

Comment: @SuperHeroY first, Yves Daoust has the primary point regarding char, but I sense you're not specifically asking about char, but about allocations more generally and specifically about memory management techniques. Sometimes overloading new isn't the best solution. A properly initialized vector of objects, for example, is actually better and simpler than the same number of objects allocated for a vector of pointers to objects.  http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/C++-mem-mgnt4.pdf is a fair cheet sheet on typical, somewhat older C++ techniques

Answer (score 3):

The allocation not only contains the allocated memory itself, but at least one word telling `delete` how much memory it has to release; moreover that is a number that has to be correctly aligned, so there will be a certain padding after the allocated char to ensure that the next block is correctly aligned. On a 64 bit machine, that means at least 16 bytes per allocation (8 bytes to hold the size, 1 byte to hold the character, and 7 bytes padding to ensure correct alignment).

However most probably that's not the only data stored; to help the memory allocator to find free memory, additional data is likely stored; if one assumes that data to consist of three pointers, one gets to a total 40 bytes per allocation, which matches your data quite well.

Note also that the allocator will also request a bit more memory from the operating system than needed for the actual allocation, so that it won't need to do an expensive OS call for every little allocation. That is, the run time library allocates larger chunks of memory from the operating system, and then cuts those in smaller pieces for your program's allocations. Thus generally there will be some memory allocated from the operating system (and thus showing up in the task manager), but not yet allocated to a certain object in your program.